# Does threading behaviour of eval() vary across different browsers?

Tags: javascript, eval, timing

I am currently logging an AJAX application with messages which include the times of certain interactions. So I have a couple of places where the code follows a pattern such as this:

```
var startTime = new Date();
this.doFunction();
var endTime = new Date();
logger.log("doFunction took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds.");
```

What I'm look to do is separate the timing into one library function, which takes a function as a parameter, to look something like:

```
time : function(toTime) {
    var startTime = new Date();
    eval(toTime);
    var endTime = new Date();
    logger.log(toTime + " took " + (endTime - startTime) + " milliseconds.");
}
```

(Syntax may be wrong, I'm not too familiar with JavaScript)

So that then instead of doing the timing I would just do:

```
time(this.doFunction);
```

My question is, do different browsers have different behaviour when it comes to `eval()`? Such as firing off the eval into a new thread, thus rendering my timing incorrect?

Any other advice on timing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. All browsers are single-threaded in the javascript engine. I suspect that you can also solve this problem simply by invoking toTime() as a function instead of using eval(). You may want to look into the javascript [arguments](http://www.seifi.org/javascript/javascript-arguments.html) object and the javascript "[call](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch07_05.htm)" and "apply" methods to transparently forward the arguments passed to your outer "time" function to the inner "toTime" function.

Answer (score 0):

Eval should be synchronous.

You shouldn't use `eval()` but `toTime.call()`, because you should avoid using eval.

Comment: Why is it that I should avoid using eval()? I don't think I will, but I'm just curious..

Comment: Because eval() can make it easy for other people to insert malicious javascript and in most cases one does not need to use eval().

Comment: Ah, never considered that. Cheers.